# Sync a local android database with mysql in real time when the device is online (Bidirectional sync)

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I am trying to develop a to-do android app that should allow me to add items to a list and save it in the local sql-lite database (in offline mode). Later when i connect to the internet I want the app to sync the data (perform  SELECT / INSERT / UPDATE operation for example) with a remote MySql database and probably show some additional information (fetched form mysql) about those items on the list. I read about some similar problems and suggestions here, but those were kind of old and focused more on methods or tactics that can be used. This SELECT/UPDATE has to be very spontaneous/real-timed and without any user interference. Is there any standard solution to this sort of problem? Does android SyncAdapter comes into play by any chance? Tips/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The changes are client side only?

Comment: @Marcus Not really, it meant to be bidirectional , for example the list created in offline mode should be inserted in the remote mysql when online. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Why are you stressing "in real time"? Are you asking how to detect changes in the Android network connectivity status?

Comment: That's still client side. Will changes be made on the server to the user's data or only from the App? Should it sync between multiple devices?

Comment: @MarcusAdams being not too pro did some research b4 answering you.. the changes will be made only from the app. About syncing from multiple devices, as far as i understood, once all the data of a particular user (synced and updated) is there in the remote server, it shouldnt matter from which device u r accessing it (or i might be wrong).

Comment: @CL. actually by real time i wanted to give importance to the fact that the whole sync opertaion will be performed as soon as the device finds an active connection without user pressing any button saying he / she wants to upload his list to the remote server.. hope i could answer ur question.. thanks